# DES/AES invertibility

Tags: encryption, aes, des, feistel-network, spn

My professor has posted a couple of practice questions that so far I haven't been able to find the answer for and I was hoping you could help.

> DES  would  remain  invertible—it  would  still  be  ablockcipher—even if its S-boxes were arbitrarily changed (the number of input and outputbits remaining the same).
>
> AES  would  remain  invertible—it  would  still  be  ablockcipher—even if its S-boxes were arbitrarily changed (the number of input and outputbits remaining the same).

I've been trying to figure out the "how" and "why", mostly.

Comment: Take a look at this DES implementation in excel, and see if it helps you : https://www.nayuki.io/page/des-cipher-internals-in-excel

Comment: While we are happy to help with homework, we require that you have at least attempted to answer the questions yourself. We will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Its not homework but thank you for the snarkyness.

Answer (score 4):

DES is a [Feistel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) cipher where the round function doesn't need to be invertible. Therefore, when designing a Feistel cipher you will have invertible and non-invertible S-box options.

In contrast, AES is a [substitution-permutation network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution-permutation_network) where the structure is completely different. If AES operations are not invertible, you will not be able to decrypt anything. So, the second claim is wrong.

Comment: the note about the input and output bits remaining the same implies the new s-box would be bijective and thus invertible

Comment: @RichieFrame The number of output bits doesn't guarantee that the S-Box will be an onto function. It just defines the range of the S-Box. We can design, though won't be secure, S-Box's that only output even, or similar properties. There are $n!$ one to one functions, and there is a total of $n^n$ functions from $n \to n$.

Comment: Let's maybe not just answer homework (or non-homework practice) questions outright?  One can suggest hints that don't spoil the problem by thoughtlessly revealing the answer.